# Ensure all team is on the right version of bit cloud bvm

Tags: npm, asdf

I am doing some investigation on how to ensure our team always has the latest version of a @teambit/bvm bit cloud node package in our react app. Something to enforce the latest version...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@teambit/bvm.install

In our gitlab file, we are using the command to install the latest, so we estimate there will be a conflict one of these days between what is on the users local and when running the pipeline script:

`npx @teambit/bvm install'

Just thinking of a possible solution. We are using asdf to manage package versions, is there a way to write a script to check the version?

https://asdf-vm.com/manage/versions.html#install-latest-stable-version

Let me know if anyone has a good solution.

Thanks

Have not tried anything yet...